# How to change xpath to css in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue in selenium.
I have this xpath that is working well

```
//*[@id='info_country']//div[contains(@class,'ant-select-selection-selected-value')
```

and I try to change it and use css selector instead of xpath
I write this code:

```
#info_country .ant-select-selection-selected-value ng-tns-c17-151 ng-star-inserted
```

and the consul not find the path

can someone advise
this is the consul and I pointed the element I want to locate

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-tns-c17-151` and `ng-star-inserted` are separate classes, you need to state it in the selector using `.`. Currently, the selector treats `ng-tns-c17-151` and `ng-star-inserted` as tags

```
#info_country .ant-select-selection-selected-value.ng-tns-c17-151.ng-star-inserted
```

The direct translation will be without those classes

```
#info_country .ant-select-selection-selected-value
```

Comment: If I am in the consul and want to get the text.  How do I do it?    #info_country .ant-select-selection-selected-value.text()         #info_country .ant-select-selection-selected-value/text()   not worked

Comment: @Bastian Use a variable and `textContent` `a = $("#info_country .ant-select-selection-selected-value")[0] a.textContent`

Comment: Not in the java code, I want to test it in the F12 chrome consule

Comment: @Bastian Yes, I know. This is for the console.